# How can I get multiple/nested class return values from deserializing json.net in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, json.net

Some background: My json data is coming from a php script that queries a mysql database. I have a class for the results of the command, such as success or failure. I have another class that will contain the actual results of the query.

```
public class jsonResults {
    public int success { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public ArrayList resultArray { get; set; }
}

public class HeroDetails {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

I think I should be able to iterate over the jsonResults results arraylist to populate a new HeroDetails but I can't seem to find how.

example json data

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "message": "Data Available!",
    "resultArray":[
        { "id": "26", "name": "Hero1" },
        { "id": "13", "name": "Hero2" },
        { "id": "1", "name": "Hero3" },
        { "id": "18", "name": "Hero4" }
    ]
}
```

This code lets me access the success and message but I'm not finding any way to get the array results into my list.

```
        List<HeroDetails> heroList = new List<HeroDetails>();
        jsonResults r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonResults>(json));

        Debug.Log("Success: " + r.success);
        Debug.Log("Message: " + r.message);
```

Comment: Just change `public ArrayList resultArray` to `public List<HeroDetails> resultArray`

Comment: It's not always going to be HeroDetails that I get back though. The jsonResult is used for any json I need to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You JSON response can contain generic data and so you need a generic result class.

```
public class jsonResults<T> {
    public int success { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<T> resultArray { get; set; }
}
```

Also you have to know what kind of type you are expecting from the request to deserialize it.

```
jsonResults<HeroDetails> r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonResults<HeroDetails>>(json);
```

Comment: That's what I was missing. Works just as I need now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you have a problem in your arraylist !! you can use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) .

```
public class ResultArray
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int success { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<T> resultArray { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The ResultArray class will change. It's not always going to be that. I need a way to have a generic array that I can then feed to whatever class I'm getting data for.

Comment: you can use generic type T . i modified my answer  !!

Comment: I've used json2csharp before but it didn't register it could help for this problem. Sir Rufo beat you to the generic type though. I've accepted his as the answer. Thanks for the help!